# The following branches form a loop of rigid branches (shorts) when added to the circuit in Cadence Virtuoso

Tags: cadence, virtuoso

I'm trying to build a Full Adder in Cadence Virtuoso using 2inp NAND Gate symbol. But I'm getting the following error,
[image: error]

This is the circuit,
[image: circuit]

Schematic of the symbol,
[image: Schematic]

What is the mistake and the solution??

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... it cannot be copied and searched on the internet ... please post the actual text instead

Comment: Shall I believe the transistor labels or the transistor pictograms?

Comment: (Shall I believe in a NAND output feeding back into one of its inputs?)